# XCopy specific txt files in multiple subfolders without subfolder in path

Tags: command-prompt, xcopy, copy-item

I have a batch file to copy over files from Web folder to my local folder.

Web folder destination look like this:

```
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\1.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\1_total.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\2.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\2_total.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\3.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\3_total.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\4.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\4_total.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\5.txt
G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\5_total.txt
```

The script I uesd:

```
xcopy /s "G:\program files\2023\subfolder_1\*.txt" c:\temp\myfiles\lessons
```

Then local destination look like this:

```
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\1.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\1_total.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\2.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\2_total.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\3.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\3_total.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\4.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\4_total.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\5.txt
c:\myfiles\lessons\subfolder_1_5\5_total.txt
```

I desired:

```
c:\temp\myfiles\lessons\1.txt
c:\temp\myfiles\lessons\2.txt
c:\temp\myfiles\lessons\3.txt
c:\temp\myfiles\lessons\4.txt
c:\temp\myfiles\lessons\5.txt
```

I only want to copy `.txt` but exclude `_total.txt` ,also don't contain subfolder in my local folder.What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem/Question

You have subfolder 1 now
I suppose you have 2,3 and 4 as well?

xcopy /s "G:\program files\2023*.txt" "c:\temp\myfiles\lessons"

/s will copy subfolders as well, in this case all txt-files in each subfolder

For exclude it should be some like /exclude:"*_total.txt"

EDIT - I was a little to fast in my answer :)
Create a txt file, add only
_total.txt

and use this as /exclude
Ex. /exclude:excludedfileslist.txt

Then it will skip copy that file as well

Good luck

Comment: thank you for answering. Yes,I have large number of subfolder under G:\program files\2023\!! Let me try you code.

Comment: it's show can't read _total.txt  , ```xcopy /s  /exclude:"*_total.txt" "G:\program files\2023*.txt" "c:\temp\myfiles\lessons"

Comment: read my edit - make sure you run xcopy from same folder you have file in